# Access a property of interface inside interface [Typescript]

Tags: reactjs, typescript, interface

I'm trying to make a react component that accepts a `data` and `dataKey` prop.
But I want to make sure `dataKey` exists as a key in `data` (along other properties in data). something like this

```js
interface Props<T> {
  dataKey: string;
  data: { [dataKey]: string } & T; //This is not acceptable.
}
```

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: what is in type T please?

Comment: I just wanted to show data can have some other things too, but it must have dataKey property. That T is whatever you want to be inside data in addition to dataKey.

Comment: Do you care if `typeof props[props.dataKey] === "string"`?  If so then does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/w8o0VW) meet your needs?  I could write up an answer if that works for you; otherwise please let me know what I'm missing.

Comment: Yes, it does. I would appreciate it if you write an answer. thanks a lot.